# How is mozilla.org homepage design acheived?

Tags: website-design, css, html

https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/

Can anyone comment how the below is acheived?

1) the sliding image album in the homepage

2) Shadow behind thumbnails in https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/products/

If it is just custom CSS or is there any accelerators that I can use for making good looking pages like above in a short time?

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it has nothing to do with design, and is also fairly demanding.

Comment: disagree on "nothing to do with design". I could see lots of web development tags too here. Edited the question,aplogies if it wasn't phrased well.

Comment: Design is about *how something looks*. Functional javascript questions are more development than design.

Comment: @Dbza Web Development tags being the key operative in your statement. We are not about Web Development, we are about design. If you were asking for tips on how to design an image slider it would be on-topic. How to code (develop) an image-slider is not on topic. It is a fine line, and your edit does help since you're no longer asking for step-by-step instructions on how to make it. But it's still primarily about development.

Comment: I thought it was leaning towards design, than a typical technical question in stackoverflow. Anyways, will keep   in mind in future that there are strict rules here.

Comment: On a side note, are these strict "fitting into stackoverflow format" rules making the whole knowledge exchange process any easier? maybe i should ask in meta ;) thanks guys

Comment: @dbza it is more design than StackOverflow but that doesn't mean its on-topic here. There is a proposal for a webdesign exchange that focuses on html/css. You should try following it. http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/58647/web-design

Comment: As far as strict rules - its a crapshoot. You'll get more helpful answers if you post something detailed that shows us you tried on your own and just got stuck on a certain part. Like if you had made the shadow in your question but it didn't look quite right. Included what doesn't look right, a screenshot, and the code. You're welcome to ask in Meta or in our chatroom (we're very active in our chat).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we are looking at the same thing. I think:

1) It is http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/api/
You can see by inspect the event listeners on any tab elements.
From there you can see lots of registered listener with prefix
cycle-* google these event names since it likely to be in the documentation. And you will get http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/api/

2) Those are box-shadow
0 0 16px rgba(0,0,0,0.1),0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5)
You can inspect it directly from the browser.

Answer (score 2):

You can examine the source code of any page to discover what is driving it.

1) It's custom javascript the page calls "Tabzilla" A link to the javascript can be acquired by examining the source code of the home page.

2) The shadows are simply CSS3 `box-shadow` properties.

As for "step-by-step instructions" that's nearly impossible here. There's simply not enough room to explain javascript and CSS and no one here knows *anything* about your current level of proficiency. You would do better by seeking an online course or educational program (perhaps http://www.lynda.com) or tutorials to learn CSS and javascript.

Answer (score 1):

A good source I often use if I want to find out the technologies used to create a webpage/website is BuiltWith.com -- it's not 100% perfect but it at least gives you a good headstart.